# Combobox SelectedItem and Binding in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, uwp

Currently Developing an UWP Application having troubles with comboboxes.

I am binding an ObservableCollection to a combobox (it works)

```
var WarehouseList = new ObservableCollection<Warehouse>(taskmag.Result);
        WarehouseBox.ItemsSource = WarehouseList;
```

What I would like to do is to show a selecteditem when I load data into my form.
I am not using MVVM and this is my Combox XAML

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="400" FontSize="32" Name="WarehouseBox" Margin="20,0,0,0">
 <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding WarehouseID}" Name="MID" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
   </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I have no idea where to start from as documentation always implies MVVM or some other thing I have not implemented.
I am willing to change my items coll to List or IEnumerable if it can help solve the issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the full thing, let me know if it still doesn't work for you:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxWarehouses">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var items = new ObservableCollection<Warehouse>();
        var item = new Warehouse() {Name = "selected"};
        items.Add(new Warehouse() { Name = "not selected"});
        items.Add(item);
        items.Add(new Warehouse() { Name = "Another Not Selected"});

        ComboBoxWarehouses.ItemsSource = items;
        ComboBoxWarehouses.SelectedItem = item;
    }
```

[image: page]

Comment: No, unfortunately that does not seem to work, I have also tried doing a List.Find and push the result into a Warehouse object and using that as a selected item but still nothing.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT,  worked in a test project I made.  page shows up with the item "selected" selected.

Comment: @Fonzusys, this code works fine by my side, maybe you can post your cs code, so can we see what exactly gets wrong with your code.

Comment: It works now, I had to change a few things in my part of the code. Thanks!